# Airflow emr cluster termination being called before step completion

Tags: python, apache-spark, boto3, airflow, amazon-emr

I am launching a cluster on EMR and submiting some steps on it using airflow.

**What i want:**

I want to terminate my cluster after all the steps added through `EmrAddStepsOperator` are complete

**What i have tried:**

I have tried using together `EmrStepSensor` and `EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator`, but my spark step gets cancelled and cluster terminates without completing all the steps

Anyone please suggest how to do it properly. here is my code

```
dag = DAG('emr_job_flow_automatic_steps_17',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         max_active_runs=1,
         catchup=True,
)


upload_to_S3_task = PythonOperator(
   task_id='upload_to_S3',
   python_callable=upload_file_to_S3,
   op_kwargs={
       'filename': '/home/ab/projects/test.py',
       'key': 'test.py',
       'bucket_name': 'dep-buck',
   },
   dag=dag)

cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
   task_id='create_job_flow2',
   job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
   aws_conn_id='aws_default',
   emr_conn_id='emr_default',
   dag=dag
)

step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
   task_id='add_steps',
   job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
   aws_conn_id='aws_default',
   steps=step,
   dag=dag
)
step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
   task_id='watch_step',
   job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
   step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
   aws_conn_id='aws_default',
   dag=dag
)

cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
   task_id='remove_cluster',
   job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
   aws_conn_id='aws_default',
   dag=dag
)

upload_to_S3_task >> cluster_creator >> step_adder >> step_checker >> cluster_remover
```

**Other Questions on stackoverflow:**

There is one similar question on stackoverflow but it has not been answered properly (using EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do it. The problem is that i was feeding `EmrStepSensor` all steps in as one `stepadder`, so as soon as one was finishing it was terminating the cluster.

The solution is to separate all steps and give the last step'id to the `EmrStepSensor`. Alternatively, i have separated only the last step with its separate step adder (`step_adder_actual_step`) from others and provided it to `EmrStepSensor`

```
step_adder_pre_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='pre_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=pre_step,
    dag=dag
)

step_adder_actual_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='actual_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=actual_step,
    dag=dag
)

step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
    task_id='watch_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('actual_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)

cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='remove_cluster',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)

cluster_creator >> step_adder_pre_step >> step_adder_actual_step >> step_checker >> cluster_remover
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, EMR was executing only one step and terminating.

```
SOLUTION: on step_checker -> step_id, change [0] for .pop()
```